# How to catch an empty reply from an API {}

Tags: node.js, json, rest

I'm currently using Node.js to fetch an API data and converting it into my own Express.js API server to send my own data (The 2 APIs I'm using changes the structure sometime and I have some users that need to keep the same structure).

So here is the code I'm using

```js
app.get('/app/account/:accountid', function (req, res) {
    return fetch('https://server1.com/api/account/' + req.params.accountid)
      .then(function (res) {
      
      var contentType = res.headers.get("content-type");
      if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
          apiServer = 'server1';
          return res.json();
      } else {
        apiServer = 'server2';
        throw "server1 did not reply properly";
      }
    }).then(server1Reconstruct).then(function (json) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return res.send(json);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }).then(function () {
      if (apiServer == 'server2') {
        server2.fetchAccount({
          accountID: [Number(req.params.accountid)],
          language: "eng_us"
        })
        .then(server2Reconstruct)
        .then(function (json) {
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          return res.send(json);
        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
    });
  })
```

To quickly explain the code: I call server1 through a normal Fetch this answer might be {} which is where I have a problem. If the accountid doesn't exist the server returns an JSON response with no errors to grab...

What should I do to be able to catch it... And If I catch it switch to server 2.

(Don't be too confused about server2 call as it's another package).

Comment: Why not just check if it's an empty object instead of catching - which means that an error has been thrown out?

Comment: how would one do that at that level? My problem is that if I try to take the variable res it doesn't  show me the JSON but the whole reply. I've tried a few things but it seems to say that it still waits for an answer... Let me try again what I did and come back to you in a minute.

Comment: If I try a console.log(res.json()); it returns "Promise { <pending> }" (this is just as a try)

Comment: Yes because `.json()` is a promise, you need to deal with it in the `.then(server1Reconstruct).then(function (json) {...HERE YOUR CODE WITH JSON ...}`

Comment: Maybe check the HTTP SC, if you get a specific resource and it does not exist there should be a different statuscode (for example 404) instead of the 200 when a resource is found and returned.

Comment: That's a great try... Unfortunately it's a 200... He is aware that it's a problem if the ID doesn't exist... But for now it's not doable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should follow those steps :

- fetch the initial API
- call the `.json()` method on the result - which returns a promise
- deal with the json response in the first `.then(json => ...)`, and here check if the result is `{}` then call server2, else call server1

BTW, your code looks very messy with all those `then` and `catch`, I recommend putting some stuff into functions, and using `async/await` if you can.

Here is some pseudo-code sample that you could use :

```
function server2Call() {
    return server2.fetchAccount({
        accountID: [Number(req.params.accountid)],
        language: 'eng_us'
    })
        .then(server2Reconstruct)
        .then(function (json) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return res.send(json);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

app.get('/app/account/:accountid', function (req, res) {
    return fetch('https://server1.com/api/account/' + req.params.accountid)
        .then(res => {
            var contentType = res.headers.get('content-type');
            if (contentType && contentType.includes('application/json')) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                server2Call()
            }
        })
        .then(json => {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            if (json is {}) return server2Call()
            else return res.send(json);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
});
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I had my error proofing if the answer is not ok? if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json"))

Is there any way that I can add it to it?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using glitch as a service... They can't use the => But I'll try to convert your function... I think I know how... I'll try and let you know

Comment: That's just a replacement for `function(res) {...}` you can replace it :)